# Bootstrap DateRangePicker shows calendar on page load

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I want to display Calendar with given date range using DateRangePicker.
http://www.daterangepicker.com/

But it is display calendar only when click input field.
I want display calendar when page load without input field.
Anyone have an idea to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add id to your datepicker field like :

```
<input id="datepicker" class="datepicker" name="datepicker"/>
```

And use jQuery to show datepicker on page load.
jQuery will be like:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#datepicker").trigger("click");
});
```